# Linear functional with only one property

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $f:\mathbb{Z}^{\omega} \to \mathbb{Z}$ be a linear functional such that $f(e_i)=0$ for all $i$ where the $j$th term of $e_i$ is $\delta_{ij}.$ Does it follow that $f \equiv 0$?

Here's my progress so far: All eventually zero sequences are in the kernel of $f,$ so the kernel is infinite-dimensional. However, so is the domain of $f,$ so this doesn't mean anything. But this does allow us to set $a \sim 0$ if $a$ is eventually zero and $a \sim b$ if $a-b \sim 0.$ Then $\sim$ partitions $\mathbb{Z}^{\omega}$ into equivalence classes, and $f$ is constant on each class.

What prevents us from setting $f \equiv 1$ on the class containing $(1,1,1,\dots)$ and then filling in the rest of the values to avoid a contradiction? Nothing as far as I know. But I couldn't guarantee linearity as the only way to assign values to $f$ seems to be an invocation of the axiom of choice, and when we choose $f(a)=x, f(b)=y$ we need to be sure $f \equiv x+y$ on the class containing $a+b.$ For this reason, I suspect $f$ is always zero, but I haven't been able to prove this.

Comment: @zipirovich I can't seem to fully define any counterexample. Writing "let $f=1$ here and then fill in the rest of the values" is not rigorous.

Comment: It does not follow, but there are no "concrete" counterexamples. If you only consider bounded sequences you can use [Banach limits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach_limit) as counterexamples. For all sequences use a [Hamel basis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basis_(linear_algebra)#Hamel_basis) which includes $e_i$ as elements.

Comment: @Conifold Just one problem. The Banach limit article talks about $\mathbb{C}.$ How do I modify this so that the domain and range involve only $\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: Yeah, maybe that won't work, Banach limits necessarily assign fractions to some integer sequences. Hamel basis might be simpler. If you only include integer sequences into it, and assign integer values to them then all values should be integers.

Comment: @Conifold Got it. Just to be sure, are we using the fact that every vector space has a basis to construct the Hamel basis?

Comment: $\mathbb{Z}$ is not a field, so $\mathbb{Z}^{\omega}$ is not a vector space, it is a [module](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Module_(mathematics)) over $\mathbb{Z}$, not sure if it is free. You need an analog of Hamel basis for modules over a ring. There should be something like that, but I do not know a reference.

Comment: Me neither, but all I tried in the last 5 minutes since seeing your comment was googling "module basis" and a few similar terms. Perhaps the next time I wake up, I should ask another question: if $\mathbb{Z}^{\omega}$ has a basis or not. If it doesn't have a basis, I would be curious about the proof.

Comment: It doesn't, although the module of bounded sequences does. You should look at this [MO thread](https://mathoverflow.net/q/46475/51484), and the [answer referenced there](https://mathoverflow.net/a/10249/51484). If I read it right all homomorphisms $\mathbb{Z}^{\omega} \to \mathbb{Z}$ have finite support, and hence are determined by their values on $e_i$. In particular, if $f$ is zero on all $e_i$ then it is $0$.